# Application Insights for SharePoint Application

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-application-insights

I have configured Azure Application Insight for multiple site collection of a single web application. I've got the page, browser details but basically I need users' information and his/her current activity on my portal.

Can I get username or userId of the user who is accessing? how can I get Do I need to code? If yes, then how?

is it possible to see concurrent devices accessing my portal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the user id of a SharePoint user. It does require you to edit the page and add some code.

Detailed instructions are [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-sharepoint/#capturing-user-id).

For your second question, the answer is also yes with a caveat. You can get the number of concurrent unique users out of the box, but not necessarily the device (LG, iPhone, Android, etc.). Your best bet is to view the user chart (below) and group it by the browser version using the instructions in Segment your data.

[Users and user counts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage/#users-and-user-counts)

[Segment your data](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-metrics-explorer/#segment-your-data)

Comment: I've added that UserProfile script in master page. I did not show any username/userid

Comment: @deshaware_swap Gotcha, so you're saying that you added the entire script from Capturing User Id > Step 3 and it's not showing user data?